# Function that uses infomation from a csv file to display more infomation

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, csv

the question I have to answer is : Write a function displayTime that receives the list of runners and the number of a runner and displays the name and the time. If the number is not found on the list the function displays an error message. 
So far I have created a function which loads all the data from the excel spreadsheet and stores it as dictionaries under separate categories. The code is as follows:

```
import csv
def loadResults():
    with open('marathon.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        s = {}
        runners = []
        number = []
        time = []
        name = []
        surname = []

        for row in readCSV:

            num = row[0]
            times = row[1]
            firstname = row[2]
            surnam = row[3]

            number.append(num)
            time.append(times)
            name.append(firstname)
            surname.append(surnam)
```

However for the question I have to display the name and the time of a runner when their number is entered. So far I have:

```
    def displayTime(runners,number):
        for s in runners:
        if s['time']==number:
        print(s['name'])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, I am not 100% sure but I think it would work

```python
Variable_Name = open("marathon.csv","r")
```

and then seperate the parts of the file you want with

```python
Variable_Name.split(",")
```

tell me if it works or not